# Django - save a nested record

Tags: python, django

I want to create a nested object model in django.
e.g.

student:

```
{
  name: 'Tom',
  age: 18,
  contact: {
    phone_num: 12345678,
    email: tom12345678@gmail.com
  }
}
```

How can I create it? I've tried to use abstract model but it's not my needs.

```
class Contact(models.Model):
   phone_num = models.IntegerField()
   email = models.TextField()
   class Meta:
     abstract = True

class Student(Contact):
  name = models.TextField()
  age = models.IntegerField()
```

When I saved as:

```
student = Student(name='Tom', age=18, phone_num=12345678, email=tom12345678@gmail.com)
```

it returns:

```
{
  name: 'Tom',
  age: 18,
  phone_num: 12345678,
  email: tom12345678@gmail.com
}
```

How can I put the phone_num and email under the contact?

Answer (score 0):

It is normal for the framework to return such result, because this is the default way it works with these kind of associations (with abstract model). When you inherit from an abstract (`abstract = true`) model, in your case - `Contact`, the child automatically "takes" all of its attributes.

If you want to have *nested* connection between `Contact` and `Student`, you may want a [**one to one** relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/).

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    phone_num = models.IntegerField()
    email = models.TextField()

    # Contact now stops being abstract
    # because we use it for relationship

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    age = models.IntegerField()

    contact = models.OneToOneField(Contact)
    # ____________________^
```

With this in mind, you can now save your model as:

```
contact = Contact(phone_num=12345678, email='tom12345678@gmail.com')

student = Student(name='Tom', age=18, contact=contact)
```

Finally, the result of the last line we wrote would be your desired result:

```
{
  name: 'Tom',
  age: 18,
  contact: {
    phone_num: 12345678,
    email: 'tom12345678@gmail.com'
  }
}
```

**EDIT**:

Using **[Django REST Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/)**:

1. At first, install it via PIP:

`pip install django-rest-framework`

2. Then add it to your INSTALLED_APPS in `settings.py`
3. Create your serializers in `serializers.py`:

   ```
   from rest_framework import serializers

   from .models import Contact, Student


   class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
       class Meta:
           model = Contact
           fields = ('id', 'email', 'phone_num')


   class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
       contact = ContactSerialiezr()
       # Here is where the magic happens
       # You use *nested serialization* to get the desired result

       class Meta:
           model = Student
           fields = ('id', 'name', 'age', 'contact')
   ```
4. Finally, serialize your object into JSON:

   ```
   >>> contact = Contact(phone_num=12345678, email='tom12345678@gmail.com')

   >>> student = Student(name='Tom', age=18, contact=contact)

   >>> serializer = StudentSerialize(student)

   >>> serializer.data
   # {
   #     'id': 1,
   #     'name': 'Tom',
   #     'age': 18,
   #     'contact': {
   #         'id': 1,
   #         'email': 'tom12345678@gmail.com',
   #         'phone_num': 12345678
   #     }
   # }
   ```

Further information on *nested serialization* - [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships).

Comment: Thanks @wencakisa. It's works! But I tried to print out a json format as a api response, it returns the contact's id instead of the attributes. e.g. return JsonResponse(list(Student.objects.values()), safe=False). It responses { name: 'Tom', age: 18, contact_id:1 }. How can I get the full view of the student?

Comment: @TszHinMa You can try to use Django REST Framework (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) and especially its **serializers** - https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

Afterwards, you can benefit from the built-in *nested serialization*. I will provide additional information in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is a kind of inheritance called [Abstract class inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes). This way you are creating a model with all the fields from parent and child.

If you need two different tables, simply use a ForeignKey relating `Student` and `Contact`. You have several approaches:

#### One student has one contact.

```
class Student(Contact):
    name = models.TextField()
    age = models.IntegerField()
    contact = models.OneToOneField(Contact, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Contact(models.Model):
   phone_num = models.IntegerField()
   email = models.TextField()
```

#### One student has one contact and contact can be re-used.

```
class Student(Contact):
    name = models.TextField()
    age = models.IntegerField()
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Contact(models.Model):
   phone_num = models.IntegerField()
   email = models.TextField()
```

#### One student can have more than one contact for different purposes and contact table can be re-used.

```
class Student(Contact):
    name = models.TextField()
    age = models.IntegerField()
    contacts = models.ManyToManyField(Contact)

class Contact(models.Model):
   phone_num = models.IntegerField()
   email = models.TextField()
```

#### One student can have more than one contact and contact table can not be re-used.

```
class Student(Contact):
    name = models.TextField()
    age = models.IntegerField()

class Contact(models.Model):
   phone_num = models.IntegerField()
   email = models.TextField()
   student = models.ForeignKey(Student, related_name="contacts")
```

Comment: Thanks @ddiazp. It's works! But I tried to print out a json format as a api response, it returns the contact's id instead of the attributes. e.g. return JsonResponse(list(Student.objects.values()), safe=False).
It responses { name: 'Tom', age: 18, contact_id:1 }. How can I get the full view of the student?

Comment: Converting a relational structure into JSON is a process called serialization. You have plenty of tools to handle this. I recommend you use Django Rest Framework; it is very automatic. You should take a look at https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer and more specificly at https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization . You should never build your own API system